# Get image of a person from iPhone address book

Tags: iphone, addressbook

How do you get a person's image from an iPhone address book?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do it like this....

```
NSData  *imgData = (NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);

UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

where `person` is of type `ABRecordRef`. Now, as CFData and NSData are toll-free bridged, you can simply type cast `CFData` to `NSData` and get the image

Hope this helps.

Comment: just a note that "imgaeWithData:imgData" in the last line of the code snippet should read  "imageWithData:imgData". I fixed it

Comment: Please note that this might not be the image that the users expects since it is not the cropped version of the image. See [ChangUZ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6953492/784318)

Comment: @Besi But with out mentioning any image format is advantageous as while populating the images in cells of table view,we use image view as accessory view,because it automatically resizes the image and sets each image in unique format(same dimensions) :)

Comment: person is an ABRecordRef.

Answer (score 12):

```
(NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat([targetPeople objectAtIndex:index], kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)
```

This is faster since it returns a thumbnail.

Comment: +1 because in addition to being a thumbnail it can be that the contact's image was cropped so ChangUZ's approach would return the same image that is shown in the address book.

Comment: But this method is available from iOS 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly refreshed code:

```
UIImage *image = nil;

@try
{
    CFDataRef cfImage = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
    // or CFDataRef cfImage = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
    if (cfImage)
    {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData*)cfImage];
        CFRelease(cfImage);
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    //...
}
```