# Getting the cropped version of a picture from the address book

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I load a contacts picture from the address book using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];

    return NO;
}
```

However, this code returns the full image that is stored rather than the cropped version, that is shown in various places, like the Addressbook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image of a person from AddressBook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085959/get-image-of-a-person-from-addressbook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953492/784318

```
NSData *imageData = (__bridge NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```