# how to get the image from contacts

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook

I have added the framework:

```
#import "AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h"
#import "AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h"
```

I want to get the image.you can modify my code ,or give me links

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef nameArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople (addressBook);

    m_SourceContactsUserArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<CFArrayGetCount(nameArray); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(nameArray, i);
        NSString *personName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        [m_SourceContactsUserArray addObject:personName];
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(nameArray);
```

thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image of a person from AddressBook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085959/get-image-of-a-person-from-addressbook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below links will definitely help you...

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/02/get-image-from-contact-stored-in-addressbook/

or

[Get image of a person from iPhone address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085959/get-image-of-a-person-from-addressbook)